# Jquery, how to: firstly fadeout clicked div, later the others

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

**HTML**

```
<div id="wrapper">
<div class="test1">
    <img src="x-led.png">
</div>
<div class="test2">
    <img src="x-led.png">
</div>
<div class="test3">
    <img src="x-led.png">
</div>
</div>
```

**JQUERY**

```
<script>
$('#wrapper img').click(function() {
var to = 10000;
var from = 1000;
var number1 = Math.floor(Math.random()*(to-from+1)+from);
var number2 = Math.floor(Math.random()*(to-from+1)+from);
var number3 = Math.floor(Math.random()*(to-from+1)+from);

$('.test1').fadeOut(1000, function() {
    $('.test1').html('You Won: ' + number1).fadeIn(3000);
});
$('.test2').fadeOut(1000, function() {
    $('.test2').html('You Won: ' + number2).fadeIn(3000);
});
$('.test3').fadeOut(1000, function() {
    $('.test3').html('You Won: ' + number3).fadeIn(3000);
});
 });
 </script>
```

Hello. I want to ask how to make, to firstly fadeout and fadein clicked DIV, and after the others div ?

And maybe it could be done more compact with cycles (for, while) or something, because i dont think its normal to do like this.

Sorry, i'm new to javascript, but i'm php programmer.

Comment: Just a heads up, this isn't Java, but Javascript (jQuery to be more specific). There is quite the difference between the two so you might want to rephrase your post and remove the Java tag as well. Oh, and "cycles" are called "loops" I knew what you meant, but not everybody will so you'll probably have better luck in the future using the correct terminology.

Comment: Sorry, i said i'm new on this, so i dont really know that terminology. I'll change the tags.

Comment: No need to apologize, I just wanted to make sure you got the right answer by asking the right question. Glad to see Palpatim's answer worked for you. Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, @Dryden Long's answer is workable for the problem as presented, but it nests pretty deeply as soon as we start adding more divs. Another solution (assume each div has a `data` attribute containing the appropriate number. Even more appropriately, store the number in a memory object rather than attaching it to the DOM) relies on iterating over the element's `siblings()`:

```
var $clickedImg = $(e.target);
var $clickedDiv = $clickedImg.parent();
var $siblings = $clickedDiv.siblings();

$clickedDiv.fadeOut(1000, function () {
    $clickedDiv.html('You Won: ' + $clickedDiv.data('num')).fadeIn(3000, function () {
        $siblings.each(function (i, e) {
            var $sib = $(e);
            $sib.fadeOut(1000, function () {
                $sib.html('You Won: ' + $sib.data('num')).fadeIn(3000);
            });
        });
    });
});
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/Palpatim/qk4Ba/ for a demo.

Comment: +1 Yes, this is much better solution for the long-term. I went with the "simpler" route, but OP should choose this as the correct answer if he understands it.

Answer (score 0):

In order to run your functions sequentially, change your code to this:

```
$('.test1').fadeOut(1000, function() {
    $('.test1').html('You Won: ' + number1).fadeIn(3000, function () {
        $('.test2').fadeOut(1000, function() {
            $('.test2').html('You Won: ' + number2).fadeIn(3000, function () {
                $('.test3').fadeOut(1000, function() {
                    $('.test3').html('You Won: ' + number3).fadeIn(3000);
                });
            });
        });
    });
});
```

The term used for this is `callback` Essentially, jQuery runs the first function, and once it finishes, the second begins and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution. It scales based on however many test divs you have and will fadeOut and fadeIn in sequence starting from your original click.

HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
 <div class="test1"><img src="x-led.png"></div>
 <div class="test2"><img src="x-led.png"></div>
 <div class="test3"><img src="x-led.png"></div>
</div>
```

JS/JQuery:

```
var winMin = 1000;
var winMax = 10000;
function fadeAfterSequence(element) {
 element.fadeOut(1000, function() {
  var winAmmt = Math.floor(Math.random() * (winMax - winMin + 1) + winMin);
  element.html('You Won: ' + winAmmt);
  element.fadeIn(1000, function() {
   fadeAfterSequence(element.next());
  });
 });
}
$(document).on('ready', function() {
 $('#wrapper img').on('click', function() {
  fadeAfterSequence($(this).parent());
 });
});
```

Working Fiddle Demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/6RsVD/

Answer (score -1):

I'm not good with the coding, but I suggest instead of using .fadeOut() or .fadeIn() function you can look in to .toggle()

try to look at the documentation: http://goo.gl/Oawz0B

Comment: `.toggle()` does not have the same animation as the fades... There is `.fadeToggle()` though. Also, this is better left as a comment, rather than an answer.